# Trying to run Nema 34 stepper motor, using DM542 driver and Beaglebone black vc

Tags: stepper-motor, beaglebone

I am trying to run a Nema 34 stepper motor, using a DM542 driver connected to external power supply and beaglebone blackvc. The driver needs 5 volts to run and I am confused on how to get 5 volts to output from the beaglebone. I know I can run 5 Volts through the barrel jack, can I then run that 5 volts through the GPIO pins? or only through the VDD 5V or SYS 5V pins? Any help would understanding the way inputs and outputs work with the different pins would be appreciated.